# Way to check input element changes in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to check any of the HTML components (i.e input elements) value in a form got changed so that i can pop up a alert saying "would like to save changes?" before navigating to other page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `jQuery` in your question:

After page load, use [$.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to create a snapshot of the form.

On submit, run serialize again.

Then you can use use (or create) an `isEqual` function to compare if there has been a change.

This question might help you on that last step:  [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

**EDIT**

jQuery also has a `serializeArray` method which may make that process easier.

https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('.form_component').change(function (){..});` , where `form_component` should be a class common for all your input elements in the form.

Comment: Agreed!. But i would like to cover this scenario as well. Lets say if a user changes the value from 0 to 1 and then changes back to 0. Ideally, in this case nothing has been changed. Is there a way to cover as this well

Comment: If you're looking to show an alert only before the user navigates away, store the form values in an array. Check if the new values is equal to the array stored. If not, show an alert. Voila!